# Validators IsNumber() inside an array of objects does not work in NestJS

Tags: arrays, validation, object, numbers, nestjs

I want to implement a validators for my class.
I have two class and one of these is called as array of object in one of my class attribute:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWK7j.png)
When I try to send the json through postman, the validators tells me that:
`must be a number conforming to the specified constraints`
This is my ValidationPipe in the **main.ts**:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
new ValidationPipe({
  disableErrorMessages: false,
  enableDebugMessages: true,
}));
```

And this is my method in **controller**:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
@Post()
async create(@Body() createDiscussion: CreateDiscussionDto): Promise<Discussion> {
  return await this.discussionService.createDiscussion(createDiscussion);
}
```

How is this possibile if I'm sending the value as number?
Thanks

I expect that the error message will disappear and works when I really send a not number value.

Comment: I've tried it myself and I haven't met any problem. Are you sure your code is up to date ? What does your application `ValidationPipe` look like ?

Comment: @reginald The code is up to date. My ValidationPipe is in main.ts: `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({disableErrorMessages: false, enableDebugMessages: true,}));` In the controller class this is my method: `async create(@Body() createDiscussion: CreateDiscussionDto): Promise<Discussion> {...}`

Comment: I've tried it again using your parameters but it still works for me.
Are you sure you're importing the right DTO classes? Haven't you got any duplicate that you might have imported instead?

Comment: @reginald I have the same problem even in the new application that I've created for testing. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I'll give you the link for my stackblitz that use the same dto. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nestjs-typescript-starter-vrbfxh?file=src/app.controller.ts)  If you try using this json in body request you'll get the errors. My body: `{"question": "test","answers": [{"value:": "value 1","like": 20 } ]}`

Comment: Ok thanks for the details + StackBlitz. I've found your problem and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't come from your codebase. It actually comes from your request body.

When you take a deeper look at the JSON from your Postman request, there is a `:` character inside the property name `"like:":` while it should just be `"like":`.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking only the code and hadn't noticed the request in json body.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark the topic as resolved by validating the answer.